# Is this a correct implementation of remove_from_front in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, heap-memory

Just wanted to know if this is a correct implementation of remove_from_front.

```
struct lnode {
    int item;
    struct lnode *next;
};

// remove_from front consumes a linked list that is stored on the heap and removes the first list.
    void remove_from_front(struct lnode **list) {
    struct lnode *next = (**list).next;
    free(*list);
    *list = next;
    }
```

Comment: @EOF I added the definition of struct lnode :)

Comment: this looks ok, are you having a problem with it?  If your not having a problem, then this question is off topic and probably should be posted in stackcodereview.com

Comment: If you reorder the sequence of resetting the `*list = nextpointer`, `free(currentpointer)`, the function may be easier to adapt to concurrency.

Comment: Sorry im kinda new to stack

Comment: check NULL  before use `*list`.

Comment: Is it working as intended?

Comment: @EOF what are the advantages of doing this?

Comment: The advantage to reordering would be small, but it would show the intention that `*list` always points to a valid `struct lnode`. Currently it may point at a `free()`'d object temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

It looks okay as far as functionality is concerned. Now for some robustness tips :

- As-is the function will go haywire (and generally segfault) if the list is empty. This may be desirable, but shall be documented.
- The function checks neither for the above case, nor for an eventual `NULL` parameter. This should be `assert`ed.

Reworked :

```
// Removes the head from a non-empty list whose nodes have been malloc'ed.
void remove_from_front(struct lnode **list) {
    assert(list && "The parameter must not be NULL");
    assert(*list && "The list must not be empty");

    struct lnode *next = (**list).next;
    free(*list);
    *list = next;
}
```